# PN junction - Voltage difference in neutral regions

Tags: electric-circuits, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, material-science, electronic-band-theory

At the very moment when a p material and a n material are put together, the conduction band and valence band of both materials are at approximately the same level. The n side and p side are both neutral. The energy of electrons on the n side is approximately the same as the energy of electrons on the p-side.

When the pn junction has reached equilibrium, their voltage are different - the energy of electrons on the n side becomes signicantly lower than the energy of electrons on the p-side. I want to know how the difference in energy of electrons come into sight during the process of reaching equilibrium?

Comment: *At the very moment when a p material and a n material put together, the conduction band and valence band of both materials are at the same level.* The Fermi levels need to align as shown in the animation, [Demo video on Fermi Level Alignment at PN Junction ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uIZfBlsaoU)

Comment: Yes, I know the Fermi level has to be aligned at equilibrium on both sides. But I would want to know what exactly is making the electrons on the p-side gaining potential energy(or electrons on n-side losing potential energy) during the process of reaching equilibrium.

Comment: @Matt (the OP, not me) If you were to make a pn junction by bringing two blocks of material together (which is not how it is typically done) there would not be a change in energy as you describe. The Fermi levels should still be aligned in the semiconductor-air-semiconductor system.

Comment: @Matt (OP) Also consider that the electron affinity (CB edge to vac level) is a material constant. So even though your CB and VB edges are curved it still takes the same amount of energy to remove an electron from the CB edge to vacuum on both sides of the junction.

Comment: Is this question substantially different from https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/728332/how-does-the-highest-energy-electrons-diffuse-to-the-p-side-from-the-cb-of-n-sid

Comment: @Matt Thank you for enlightening by mentioning about vacuum level. You are right. The electron affinity are about the same on both the n-side and the p-side. However, the potential energy between them are significant different so is the voltage.

Comment: @Matt I reread some related posts on why p-side has band energy higher than the n-side. If I understand them correctly, the electrons from the CB on the n-side have lower potential energy because most of those electrons came from the donor atoms which have a valence energy level close to the CB on the n-side so we only need to give them a little a bit of energy to bring them up to the CB.

Comment: @Matt On the other hand, the electrons from the CB on the p-side have higher potential energy because those electrons came from VB of the intrinsic material, so we need to give them much more energy to bring them to the CB on the p-side. Not sure if I am on the right track.

Comment: @Matt This question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/728332/how-does-the-highest-energy-electrons-diffuse-to-the-p-side-from-the-cb-of-n-sid is a closely related question. Mainly I want to know how losing high energy electrons on the n-side during the process of reaching equilibrium related to the fermi level shifting downward.